# Unprintable ASCII character found in Swift Source Code

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]

Hi, I am new to Swift language , can anyone explain why there is error with PI Symbol here.

```
import Foundation

class CalculatorBrain
{

    private var accumulator = 0.0

    func setOperand(operand : Double) {
        accumulator = operand
    }

    func performOperations (symbol: String) {
        switch symbol {
            case "π" :
                accumulator = M_PI
            case "√" :
                accumulator = sqrt(accumulator)
            default : break
        }
    }

    var result : Double {
        get{
            return accumulator
        }
    }
}
```

reference
https://youtu.be/j50mPzDMWVQ?t=2303

Comment: Please also include this snippet *as text* in your question so that we can test. Thanks.

Comment: @EricAya added code

Comment: I've just pasted your code into a Playground and there's no such error for me, it works.

Comment: I have also checked in Playgrond, there's is no error.

Comment: Probably a control-space or something like that. Just delete and re-type the line

Comment: thanks @MartinR rewriting helped..

Answer (score 19):

In Xcode: "Editor" menu, "Show Invisibles". That will show you invisible characters in your source code.

Answer (score 12):

This answer is for the people who are using windows keyboard with mac system.

While typing you might have unknowingly clicked the **right click** key in your keyboard, which will create the Unprintable ASCII character that is causing the **Unprintable ASCII character found in source file** error.

To check this go to find and click the **right click** key and you can find them in your class and delete those characters and the error will be gone.

Thanks

Comment: Whoever worked this out deserves a nobel prize.

Comment: Incredible that Swift is flagging this as an error!

Answer (score 3):

If you open it in a terminal with an editor such as Vim, you will see that it contains ASCII characters.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaSjx.png)

Answer (score 2):

I copied/pasted the line to VSCode, where it shows clearly:

You can't see the problem in XCode,
[image]

but you can in VSCode:

[image]

Just hit the backspace key once in XCode where the invisible red character is, and you'll see that the cursor doesn't go backwards, because it just deleted the invisible character.